# Getting value of invalid field after MethodArgumentNotValidException

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

My entity class is annotated with `@NotNull` of hibernate for one of the field.I am catching the exception in `@ExceptionHelper`. My problem is that i want to access the value of the invalid field so that i can add it into the logger.

Here is the `ExceptionHandler`:

```
@ExceptionHandler({ MethodArgumentNotValidException .class })
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> handleInvalidMethodArgException(MethodArgumentNotValidException  de) {
    List<FieldError> bindingResult = de.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors();
    LOGGER.debug(String.format("Start : %s : handleDataexception()", this
                .getClass().getSimpleName()));

    for(FieldError fieldError: bindingResult){
        LOGGER.debug("Invalid {} value submitted for {}", 
                            fieldError.getRejectedValue(), fieldError.getField());
    }

    ErrorMsg = new ErrorMsg(errorCode, errorMessage);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errMsg, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

I have added `@Validated` with the `@RequestBody` in the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entity won't store incorrect values furthermore it is bad practise to use entity object on the front. You should create a DTO object, than send it to your application. Check it (here you could add incorrect staff to logger) and then process it to your entity object and try to save or whatever you want to do. 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.I cant see any link that could help to add incorrect stuff to logger.

Comment: I added simple image with my concept. Assembler is a class which process your entity to dto and your dto to entity. Transfer/Validation is a place where you can add your log. DTO - Data Transfer Object, object created only to transfer necessery data from view to model and vice versa. It could contain less fields then entity ( all field that you need to present).

Comment: Hi, I have a question how does the assembler part work? In my project I have used BeanUtils.copyProperties to copy fields from the dto to the entity objject? Is that correct? What are some other more intuitive/standard ways of doing it?

Answer (score 13):

[`MethodArgumentNotValidException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/messaging/handler/annotation/support/MethodArgumentNotValidException.html#getBindingResult--) has a `getBindingResult` method that returns the [`BindingResult`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html) if the failure is validation-related, or `null` if none. So, you can call the `getFieldErrors` method which returns `List` of [`FieldError`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/FieldError.html)s. Each `FieldError` has a `getRejectedValue` which gives you the invalid value of the corresponding field:

```
ex.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().forEach(fieldError -> {
            LOGGER.debug("Invalid {} value submitted for {}", 
                    fieldError.getRejectedValue(), fieldError.getField());
});
```

`ex` is an instance of `MethodArgumentNotValidException`.

Comment: @Spring User You can accept and vote up a working answer and also, consider pokemzok recommendation on creating some DTO and Assemblers

Comment: But i can see MethodArgumentNotValidException on console even after adding an @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException ) in the code.

Comment: Add the exception handler to question

Comment: I have added the excpetion handler.Please check and let me know .

Comment: Where did you put the `ExceptionHandler`? In a `ControllerAdvice`? Are you sure your exception handler getting called? Put a breakpoint in `handleInvalidMethodArgException` method and make sure it's getting called

Comment: Yes i have added in a controller advice and iIt  goes inside the Exception Handler.The exception is thrown on console as it goes inside the handler.Do u have any idea why am i getting the error on console ?

Comment: May it is because you are logging the exception in the second statement of exception handler to the console.

Comment: It gives the exception as soon as it enters the handler method i.e before reaching the logger statement.I have used Logger level as debug.

Comment: What's the response of your HTTP request in the end? 500 or 404? If it's not 500, then that exception is just being logged by spring.

Comment: Yes.Its 404.So no way to avoid it on console ?

Comment: Its just a log from spring. Your exception hamdler working correctly

Comment: ok.Is there any way to ensure the order of the errors.Like if i have 3 fields in req body and i want to get field error in the bindingresult according to the order of the req body variables ?eg : {a :1.4,b:2.5,c:4.5} so if a b and c all are invalid then the error message shown to user should be only for a.But since ordering is not maintained in bindingresult,i am not able to show approprioate error.