# How to display tables from DB in Spring MVC Controller

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, controller

I have referred to -> 
[Spring MVC how to display data from database into a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575698/spring-mvc-how-to-display-data-from-database-into-a-table)

My aim is to try and understand what is the syntax and process to create queries, and whether I'm correct.

The following code tries to display all Order entities.

```
@AutoWired
private OrderService orderService;

@RequestMapping("/")
//public String orderPage(Model model) {
//  model.addAttribute("orderList", SomeApp.getStore().getOrderList());
//    return "form/orderPage"};
// this is the code I am trying to translate below

    @ResponseBody 
    public List<order> orderList(Map<String, Object> model) {
        List<order> orderList = OrderService.findALl();
        //orderRepository.findAll <- where does this come in? is it needed at all
        return orderList;
      }
```

If the Service layer is not being used, in my Repo do I only state

```
List<Order> findAll();
```

Additional Info:
Service layer is not used in this project and instead business logic will be in Controller (partly why I'm confused as to what code goes where)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `@Autowire` the `OrderRepository` so that you can call `orderRepository.findAll()` in your `Controller` as shown below. For that, you also need to define the `OrderRepository` and `Order` Entity classes.

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

    @AutoWired
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody 
    public List<order> orderList(Map<String, Object> model) {
        List<order> orderList = OrderService.findALl();
        orderRepository.findAll();
        return orderList;
      }  

}
```

**Repository:**

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Integer> {
    public Order findAll();
}
```

**Entity:**

```
@Entity
public class Order {

    //add your entity fields with getters and setters
}
```

You can refer [here](https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/) for spring-data-jpa basic example.

Comment: thanks! I have already defined those so I'll change the autowire on my controller accordingly

Comment: since the repos are extending CRUD I would just replace jpa repository with that right? And add an import statement.