# Spring Boot Validation - How to retrieve input message in MethodArgumentNotValidException handler

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

I am using `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency to validate java beans for my application

My Controller code as below

```
@PostMapping("/testMessage")
    ResponseEntity<String> testMethod(@Valid @RequestBody InternalMsg internalMsg) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Valid Message");
    }
```

InternalMsg class

```
public class InternalMsg implements Serializable {
    @NotNull(message = "Msg Num is a required field")
    private String msgNumber;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Activity Name is a required field")
    private String activityName;
}
```

InternalMsg Sample Input JSON

```
{
    "MSGNUMBER": "12345",
    "ACTIVITYNAME": "",
}
```

My handler code as below

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public ResponseEntity<InternalMsgResponse> handleValidationExceptions(
        MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    InternalMsgResponse msg = new InternalMsgResponse();
    ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {
        String errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage(); // Error Message
        ack.setStatusNotes(errorMessage);
    });
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(msg);
}
```

As per the sample input, the activity name is empty so I get a validation error message as "Activity Name is a required field".

For some other processing, I need to get the values of input Msg inside handler i.e I want to get msgNumber value(12345) which is a VALID value.

Is it possible? If so, please guide how to retrieve those values inside the handler.

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36306351/2170192

Comment: Thanks for the reference but I want to get a valid field value here. I am interested in one specific field value always which is msgNumber and here activity name is invalid

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call

```
ex.getTarget()
```

That will return the object. Then simply cast it to `InternalMsg`

If you are using an older Spring Boot Version before 2.4.x then you must call

```
ex.getBindingResult().getTarget()
```

Comment: I am not getting this method .. ex.getTarget() says "Cannot resolve method 'getTarget' in 'MethodArgumentNotValidException'"

Comment: What Spring Boot version are you using?

Comment: It is 2.3.1.RELEASE

Comment: From Spring Framework version 5.3.0, `MethodArgumentNotValidException` extends `BindException` which implements `BindingResult`, which in turn defines `.getTarget()` method.

Comment: Many thanks, it works pretty well! You saved lots of my time

Comment: Great. I'm happy to help